# auto share and send current webpage url with only one person(friend) on click of messenger button on webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, share, chatbot, messenger

i am testing facebook send button for my website and wants users to send current webpage url link to admin directly by clicking on facebook messenger button..here are javascript codes

```
<script>      
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '95100348886',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.6'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));      
</script>

<div class="fb-messengermessageus" 
     messenger_app_id="95100348886" 
     page_id="XYZ" 
     color="blue"
     size="large">
</div>
```

that was the above javascript code which i have used (you can put your page name instead of "xyz"...

and below is the html code

```
<a href="https://m.me/XYZ">
I am sending the link to admin which I liked
```

you can put your facebook page name instead of "xyz"

now these codes open direct messegner and allows user to chat with admin  and users are allowed to send message to the admin via this button of facebook messenger.

now i want to load default text when the messenger opens so that user dont need to type anything and can directly click on send button to send the **default message along with current page url.**

here is one code on which when user click it by default shares current page url but it allows user to select from the contact which i dont want as user should compulsorily send the message to admin only .

```
<div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style">
<a class="a2a_dd" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_facebook_messenger"></a>
</div>
<script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
```

hence i want "auto share and send current webpage url to only one person(friend) on click of messenger button on webpage". which is the mixture of above codes

thanks in advance

Comment: _“click here to let us know that you have liked the page”_ - I hope you are aware that you are not allowed to like-gate any more, or force users to or reward them for liking a specific page in any way. // What you want to do is not possible using this message us button. The send to messenger button however allows you to specify a custom "state" value of up to 50 characters.

Comment: i have found one code for share

Comment: maybe we can use ref parameter of "m.me" with window.location and text property of javascript ..but still i am not sure

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/referral-params.....this link can help..but still i am not sure

Comment: Sorry forgot to close the anchor tag from HTML code..